# How to get the UIView instance for a Google Map marker?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uipopovercontroller

I want to show a VC as a pop up when the user taps on one of the markers on the Google Map.

The reason that I want to do this is because I want to control the view that pops up when the marker is tapped. I tried using the `mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker)` delegate method. But I don't know how to create a view controller in that method that controls the marker info window's view.

To present a VC as a pop over, I did this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MarkerInfoController")
vc.modalInPopover = true
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
print(marker.iconView)
vc.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = marker.iconView

self.presentVC(vc) // this is from EZSwiftExtensions. Don't worry about it
```

The problem arises when I try to set the `sourceView` of the `UIPopoverPresentationController`. I thought using the `iconView` property would work, but no. There is always an error saying that `sourceView` is not set.

How can I get the `UIView` instance for the marker, so that I can assign it to `sourceView`?

P.S. This is how a marker is created:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output:
[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
  var sourceView: UIView?
}

extension MapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
  
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    mapCenterPinImage.fadeOut(0.25)
    
    // Adding a delay becuase when click on marker Camera changes it position
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
      
      let location = marker.accessibilityActivationPoint
      self.sourceView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 1, height: 1))
      self.view.addSubview(self.sourceView!)
    
      let popController = MyPopUpViewController()
      popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
      popController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.sourceView
      self.present(popController, animated: true)
    }

    return false
  }
  
}
extension MapViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{
  func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
  }
  func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
    sourceView?.removeFromSuperview()
    sourceView = nil
    return true
  }
  
}
```

What I've done basically created a UIView and added it to ViewController at runtime and set this as a source of Popup and make it nil when it's dismissed.
**marker.accessibilityActivationPoint** is the source of X and Y according to device's screen

Answer (score 0):

You can just customise the infoView of the GMS Marker instead of showing a viewControlle and perform your desired operations there. You can have a look at this article over here. I faced something similar to your issue and this helped me out. Hope it helps you out as well. :D

https://medium.com/@matschmidy/how-to-implement-custom-and-dynamic-map-marker-info-windows-for-google-maps-ios-e9d993ef46d4

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on  below is a gmsMapView delegate mehtod

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
```

here you will get the marker which you tapped , and for source view you can access

```
 marker.iconView
```

which I think will solve your problem, hope it helps :)